# rake gems:refresh_specs error on unpacked gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

Following the great advice of Chris Wanstrath, I decided to [vendor everything](http://errtheblog.com/posts/50-vendor-everything).

However, whenever I run a rake task now I get an error for each of my unpacked gems stating

> config.gem: Unpacked gem gemname in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.

I've done this but no dice. Anyone have the same issue? If so, how do I resolve?

TIA

Comment: I've had this. Unhelpfully, I didn't record what I did and I've forgotten (old age creeping in). Nonetheless, while I try to remember, it might help if you could add some info, like versions of rails, gems, rake, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike. However Milan got in there first! Cheers

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I usually go through the following steps:

1. `cd vendor/gems/gemname`
2. `gem specification gemname > .specification`

Hope it helps.

Comment: see you at SoR by the way ... I'm sure I'm due you a drink by now ;)

Comment: Hah! That sounds great! Now I understand what is the real benefit of using SO. :D

Comment: My God, how do you know this stuff? +1

Comment: NOTE: at least in the gem I did this for today, prawn-core-0.7.2, the gem name was prawn-core.

Comment: For the gem I just did this on, the gem name was "wuparty-1.0.2.unbounce.gem", otherwise I'd get an error.

Comment: Hi, im trying this for ambethia-recaptcha-0.2.2, I have tried gem specification ambethia-recaptcha-0.2.2 > .specification, gem specification ambethia-recaptcha > .specification and gem specification recaptcha > .specification and none of these work, any ideas?